# Angular2 - How to conditionally load css file in index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

What I have right now is a page with dark theme in index.html:

```
<base href="/">
<html>
<head>
    <title>XXX</title>
</head>
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/dark_room.css">
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

I also have a bright "light_room.css" theme that is required to implement, and user could switch theme base on needs. I am wondering how could I achieve this?

I thought it could be done by having an url parameter so that when user type like `?light_room=True` at the end of url, the page will load light_room.css. However I think it can only be done in normal templates but not in index.html.

Does anyone have similar experience in conditionally loading css file in index.html?

Comment: Have you tried it this way?
Let your backend generate different index.html depending on the URL-Parameters.

Comment: @Niklas I think it could be an approach but I don't know how. since setting up URL-parameters is usually done in the .ts file but index.html does not have one.

Answer (score 2):

The point is that theming is usually just some different colors. You can add all themes to one css. `my-app > .dark` gets different colors and the class will be added dynamically in the code.

Here is a more detailed example how I use it:

app-theme.scss:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();
$words-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-teal, 300);
$words-app-secondary: mat-palette($mat-indigo, 500);
$words-app-warn: mat-palette($mat-red, 500);

$words-app-theme: mat-light-theme($words-app-primary, $words-app-secondary, $words-app-warn);
@include angular-material-theme($words-app-theme);

app-words-root > md-sidenav-container.dark {
  $words-app-theme-dark: mat-dark-theme($words-app-primary, $words-app-secondary, $words-app-warn);
  @include angular-material-theme($words-app-theme-dark);
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<md-sidenav-container [class.dark]="useDarkTheme"> ... </md-sidenav-container>
```

---

**non angular version**

app.component.js

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

class AppComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document: any) {
    let head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    let link  = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'assets/dark_room.css'; // you may want to get this from local storage or location
    head.appendChild(link);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering but I am not allowed to touch the css files, so....I still need to find a way to choose those two files somehow

Comment: This will be similar problem as for title - angular 2 does not have functions for dom manipulation outside of `<app>`. For title they offer a `Title` service. But not for loading css.

Comment: Yeah, if I can include function it could be doable.

Comment: It comes up my mind that can I just create 2 index.html and load the index.html after the url, but when I type in "/index_light.html", the page always shows "loading...."